# Aggregating Hadoop job counters across multiple jobs

Tags: logging, hadoop, apache-pig

Hadoop: (ver - 1.2.1), (1 + 8 node cluster)

My use case is, I am trying to get the time taken to execute a specific pig script and how that time is being spent from a mapreduce point of view. I need to run the pig script multiple times(say 100) to get the average time. I've enabled `pig.udf.profile` which gives me time spent on each udf function as mapreduce counters. I am also interested in other latency,memory metrics reported for each job (cpu time,heap useage). I can see these counters from the jobtracker web UI( `host:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=blah`). Now, my question is, is there a way to aggregate these counters across jobs. Or, how will I build a table that looks like

```
                        Run1   Run2   Run3 ...
Cpu time              |      |      |
Redcr wait            |      |      |
UdfCntr1(approx_us)   |      |      |
UdfCntr2(approx_invc) |      |      |
CounterY(approx_us)   |      |      |
```

Each run is a different job as far as Hadoop is concerned. After grep'ing through the log folder, I figured out the counters are in the `history/done/..` folders. Is there an existing technique to combine the results, or am I doomed to write my own parser that goes through each log file. I thought the use case is common enough for an existing solution - any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options, and I apologize in advance that none of them are particularlly appealing.

***Implement a PPNL***

The *PigProgressNotificationListener* is a [java interface](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/tools/pigstats/PigProgressNotificationListener.html) for exposing events that occur over the course of a Pig job to arbitrary clients.  If you implement this interface and attach an instance of your class you can then grab hadoop counters (and many other M/R related metrics) and store them away for later usage. Note that this requires a reasonable understand of Pig internals, though not necessarily an expert level of understanding.

***Use Another System that Gathers Metrics***

Right now your options are limited [Ambrose](https://github.com/twitter/ambrose) which was open sourced by Twitter, and [Lipstick](https://github.com/Netflix/Lipstick) which was open sourced by Netflix.   I do not know for sure if Ambrose collects hadoop counters, but it could be extended to do.  Lipstick does collect hadoop counters as is.  With either of these you could then analyze the counters with a varying level of difficulty, depending on how you configured them to store data.

***Parse Your Log Files***

Sounds like you've already thought about going down this route for a couple of reasons:

1. All the other options require you to know quite about the internals of another project, be it Pig, Lipstick, or Ambrose.  If you were planning to dive into one of these for other reasons as well then go for it, but otherwise it's a big investment for a single usecase.
2. All the other options are limited to Pig jobs.  You aren't going to get this data if you run a vanilla Map/Reduce job or start working with other tooling like hive, cascading, etc.  If you build up some log parsing tooling that converts the data to a well known format that then gets processed you should be able to reuse all your code (except for the actual parsing) with hadoop tools.
3. If your data is based on your logs, and you archive all your logs, you can always backfill if six months down the road you're interested in some data point you hadn't collected before.  This isn't possible with the other approaches.
4. It's an established pattern that works.  I can't point to a lot of online resources discussing people who have taken this approach, but I have met quite a few people who independently took this approach and were happy with it.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I also found Found [This.](https://github.com/SWIMProjectUCB/SWIM/wiki/Analyze-historical-cluster-traces-and-synthesize-representative-workload) 


I was able to modify that perl script provided there to retrieve my UDF counters as well. This is not a very portable solution. But will serve my needs for the time now. Thanks for the detailed answer, I had already looked into Ambrose but PPNL is something new to me and I will explore that option.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to build a small java method that takes all of your counters and sends them to Graphite.
* Install Graphite 
* Have all your Jobs run through a central Main class which at the end of the job, takes the counters, converts into Key Value, where key can be .., and value is the counter value which is a long number. 
* Report those Key Values as CSV format graphite can read and send it through normal Socket using port 2003 (I think its the default Graphite port).
* Use Graphite Web UI to view and analyze the data.